# Codeception Acceptance Test How to find css Pseudo classes element

Tags: codeception

My Testing Html Like this :

```
<a  class="waves-effect waves-light btn red ">Delete</a>
```

Delete

I want to use css selector like :

`.red:not(.disabled):first`

But I write in Codeception Acceptance test case

```
$I->click(['css' =>'.red:not(.disabled):first']);
```

It will throw an error :

```
Strict locator is malformed: css => .red:not('.disabled):first
```

How can Codeception get this element ?

Comment: Maybe there is another way of composing the selector, please add the html snippet of the element if possible with cases for both enabled and disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to xpath selector `'(//*[contains(@class,"red") and not(@disabled)])[1]'` could help you.